# Apache httpd: Alias is inherited by virtual host?

Tags: apache2

When the default server contains

```
Alias /bla /srv/www/blub
```

then all VirtualHosts can also acecss `/bla`.

I must say I didn't anticipate that. IMO a virtual server should have its own separate config.

Is that a bug or a feature? Can I switch this behavior off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings not limited to a specific VirtualHost but placed in the main server configuration files (i.e. the [`httpd.conf`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html)  or in configuration snippets loaded with [`Include` and/or `IncludeOptional`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#include) directives)  are valid for the whole server and that includes any and all VirtualHosts.

[That is by design:](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html#scope)

> **Scope:** Directives placed in the main configuration files apply to the entire server. If you wish to change the configuration for only a part of the server, you can scope your directives by placing them in `<Directory>`, `<DirectoryMatch>, <Files>, <FilesMatch>, <Location>`, and `<LocationMatch>` sections. These sections limit the application of the directives which they enclose to particular filesystem locations or URLs. They can also be nested, allowing for very fine grained configuration.

> httpd has the capability to serve many different websites simultaneously. This is called Virtual Hosting. Directives can also be scoped by placing them inside `<VirtualHost>` sections, so that they will only apply to requests for a particular website.

Do not place directives in the main httpd.conf that you do not want to apply to all VirtualHosts.